# Python regex issue while scraping

Tags: python, regex

My piece of code is

```
getdata = bso.findAll('a', attrs={"class": "btn btn-info"})

print getdata
for elem in getdata:
    strpat= elem
    newlnk=re.findall(r'href="(.*?)"',str(strpat))
    print newlnk
```

It does have something in getdata.I want all hrefs from getdata

The error output is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
[<a class="btn btn-info" href="/auburn-al/">Visit Website</a>, 
 <a class="btn btn-info" href="/homewood-al/">Visit Website</a>, 
 <a class="btn btn-info" href="/montgomery-al/">Visit Website</a>]   
File "C:/Users/gyan/PycharmProjects/demo/testphantom", 
    line 60, in <module> parseHtml(datalink)
File "C:/Users/gyan/PycharmProjects/demo/testphantom", 
    line 18, in parseHtml
newlnk=re.findall(r'href="(.*?)"',str(strpat)) TypeError: 'ResultSet' object is not callable
```

Any help would be highly appeciated

Comment: elem has   [<a class="btn btn-info" href="/auburn-al/">Visit Website</a>, <a class="btn btn-info" href="/homewood-al/">Visit Website</a>, <a class="btn btn-info" href="/montgomery-al/">Visit Website</a>]

Comment: please make sure your question fits the quality standards. and btw, no need to use a regex here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why do you get this error, but truly there is no need to use regex.
To get all href attributes from a ResultSet you can do something like this:

```
newlinks = [a["href"] for a in getdata]
```

Comment: Thanks I am getting desired output

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the scoldings and hints.

I got the desired output by simply doing

for link in getdata:
  print link['href']